# change checkbox color in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6

I'm using angular material(6.4.7). I was using `select` and I want to change the color of select checkbox. I have tried `/deep/` and `::ng-deep` but no success. I think, I am using it in wrong way for these checkbox.

Here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jnrggmovkpn?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding this to the select-multiple-example.css works in the stack-blitz link

```
::ng-deep .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: The solution works. Can you please tell, where i can find the exact classes for each type of mat-component? For example i also want to change the color of text, the underline of the select-box etc..

Comment: I just used F12 to launch dev tools, then click the select an element button in the upper left corner, then select the element in the page. This will take you to all the styles for that element. This is how I got .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know it was a bit late for my answer but this works for me the best

```
// for color when checkbox is checked 
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background
  background-color: orange;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: orange;
}

//to change the border color 
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-frame{
  border-color: rgb(75, 75, 75, 0.7);
}
```